# How to parse email without using Mailparse PHP extension

Tags: php, parsing, email

How to parse mime email without using Mailparse PHP extension? 
Do not offer solutions like MimeMAilParser class (it's using Mailparse) or exploding using "\n\n".

Comment: you just excluded all the possibily option

Comment: Can I ask why you want to exclude this parser? At http://CloudMailin.com we quite often get requests for help decoding emails in PHP so it would be good to know why it potentially shouldn't be used?

Answer (score 1):

Your issues with Mailparse and exploding will go away if you simply remove the closing php tag   (?  >)

Answer (score 0):

Weird exclusions, but alright. Try these (from the Google machine):

Possible dupe of [Best way to handle email parsing/decoding in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721410/best-way-to-handle-email-parsing-decoding-in-php)

ezComponents has a mail parser as demonstrated at http://ezcomponents.org/docs/api/2009.2.1/introduction_Mail.html#parsing-a-message-set

Note that many of these MAY use the Mailparse extension under the hood. What is your specific issue with Mailparse?

Answer (score 0):

Try write own parser for example look here https://github.com/breakermind/PhpMimeParser/blob/master/PhpMimeParser_class.php Cut mime message and get parts what you need. It is simple class which parse multipart mime message.