# Proper way to decode incoming email subject (utf 8)

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to pipe my incoming mails to a PHP script so I can store them in a database and other things. I'm using the class [*MIME E-mail message parser* (registration required)](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3169/download/zip.html) although I don't think that's important.

I have a problem with email subjects. It works fine when the title is in English but if the subject uses non-latin Characters I get something like

```
=?UTF-8?B?2KLYstmF2KfbjNi0?=
```

for a title like 
یک دو سه

I decode the subject like this:

```
  $subject  = str_replace('=?UTF-8?B?' , '' , $subject);
  $subject  = str_replace('?=' , '' , $subject);      
  $subject = base64_decode($subject);
```

It works fine with short subjects with like 10-15 characters but with a longer title I get half of the original title with something like ��� at the end.

If the title is even longer, like 30 characters, I get nothing. Am I doing this right?

Comment: That's not the highest quality software you picked there. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721410/best-way-to-handle-email-parsing-decoding-in-php, they probably all do the decoding and don't require such receival hacks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Despite the fact that this is almost a year old - I found this and am facing a similar problem.

I'm unsure why you're getting odd characters, but perhaps you are trying to display them somewhere your charset is unsupported.

Here's some code I wrote which should handle everything except the charset conversion, which is a large problem that many libraries handle much better. (PHP's [MB library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php), for instance)

```
class mail {
    /**
      * If you change one of these, please check the other for fixes as well
     *
     * @const Pattern to match RFC 2047 charset encodings in mail headers
     */
    const rfc2047header = '/=\?([^ ?]+)\?([BQbq])\?([^ ?]+)\?=/';

    const rfc2047header_spaces = '/(=\?[^ ?]+\?[BQbq]\?[^ ?]+\?=)\s+(=\?[^ ?]+\?[BQbq]\?[^ ?]+\?=)/';

    /**
     * http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=2047
     *
     * =?<charset>?<encoding>?<data>?=
     *
     * @param string $header
     */
    public static function is_encoded_header($header) {
        // e.g. =?utf-8?q?Re=3a=20Support=3a=204D09EE9A=20=2d=20Re=3a=20Support=3a=204D078032=20=2d=20Wordpress=20Plugin?=
        // e.g. =?utf-8?q?Wordpress=20Plugin?=
        return preg_match(self::rfc2047header, $header) !== 0;
    }

    public static function header_charsets($header) {
        $matches = null;
        if (!preg_match_all(self::rfc2047header, $header, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
            return array();
        }
        return array_map('strtoupper', $matches[1]);
    }

    public static function decode_header($header) {
        $matches = null;

        /* Repair instances where two encodings are together and separated by a space (strip the spaces) */
        $header = preg_replace(self::rfc2047header_spaces, "$1$2", $header);

        /* Now see if any encodings exist and match them */
        if (!preg_match_all(self::rfc2047header, $header, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
            return $header;
        }
        foreach ($matches as $header_match) {
            list($match, $charset, $encoding, $data) = $header_match;
            $encoding = strtoupper($encoding);
            switch ($encoding) {
                case 'B':
                    $data = base64_decode($data);
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                    $data = quoted_printable_decode(str_replace("_", " ", $data));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("preg_match_all is busted: didn't find B or Q in encoding $header");
            }
            // This part needs to handle every charset
            switch (strtoupper($charset)) {
                case "UTF-8":
                    break;
                default:
                    /* Here's where you should handle other character sets! */
                    throw new Exception("Unknown charset in header - time to write some code.");
            }
            $header = str_replace($match, $data, $header);
        }
        return $header;
    }
}
```

When run through a script and displayed in a browser using UTF-8, the result is:

آزمایش

You would run it like so:

```
$decoded = mail::decode_header("=?UTF-8?B?2KLYstmF2KfbjNi0?=");
```

Comment: You can use `$data = iconv($charset, 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $data);` or
`$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', $charset);` for decoding unusual characters. I prefer the 2nd way.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [`mb_decode_mimeheader()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-decode-mimeheader.php) function to decode your string.

Comment: This is the better answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

Use php native function

```
<?php
mb_decode_mimeheader($text);
?>
```

This function can handle utf8 as well as iso-8859-1 string.
I have tested it.

Comment: This will also decode non utf8 subjects. Try if (preg_match('/\?utf-8\?/', $subject)) $subject  = mb_decode_mimeheader($subject);

Comment: That's not true as far as I can tell @Juergen. Also Prashant why did you copy TIMESPLiNTER's answer?

Answer (score 8):

Use php function:

```
<?php
imap_utf8($text);
?>
```

Comment: The imap_utf8 worked "better" than mb_decode_mimeheader. Better in the result that some characters were transformed to underscores in mb_decode_mimeheader but were correctly converted in imap_utf8.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add yet one more way to do this (or if you don't have the mbstring extension installed but do have iconv):

```
iconv_mime_decode($str, ICONV_MIME_DECODE_CONTINUE_ON_ERROR, 'UTF-8')
```

Answer (score -1):

Would the imap-mime-header-decode function help here?

Found myself in a similar situation today.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php