# How to decode string with mixed content (Latin & UTF-8) in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a PHP script that read emails/usenet messages, I found a case where I have a text that's a **mix of arabic & latin words**, ie.

`PHP and ARABIC_WORD`

ie.

`PHP and الساعة`

The problem is, the text is encoded, ie.

`Some Text =?utf-8?b?RVByaW50cyBhbmQg2KfZhNi52LHYqNmK2Kk=?=`

**My question is** How can I decode this `?utf-8?...` when it's mixed with latin text?

I'm using **PHP 5.4.15**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got is the [MIME Encoded-Word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) syntax used in email messages for non US-ASCII encoded texts:

The form is: `"=?charset?encoding?encoded text?="`.

- `charset` may be any character set registered with [IANA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority). Typically it would be the same charset as the message body.
- `encoding` can be either "Q" denoting Q-encoding that is similar to the [quoted-printable](http://php.net/quoted-printable-decode) encoding, or "B" denoting [base64](http://php.net/base64_decode) encoding.
- `encoded text` is the Q-encoded or base64-encoded text.
  -An *encoded-word* may not be more than 75 characters long, including *charset*, *encoding*, *encoded text*, and *delimiters*. If it is desirable to encode more text than will fit in an encoded-word of 75 characters, multiple *encoded-words* (separated by CRLFSP) may be used.

So this little excerpt from wikipedia also contains how you can decode the string. Sure you're not the first one who needs to do this, therefore libraries exist. See as well:

- [Best way to handle email parsing/decoding in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721410/best-way-to-handle-email-parsing-decoding-in-php)
- [proper way to decode incoming email subject (utf 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8626786/367456)

Comment: Thanks you very much hatre! Very well explained and the [second link/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13694392/1165880) fix this for me, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be encoded text: try with php function  base64_decode.

```
$my_string = 'test string';
$res = base64_encode($my_string);
echo $res; //dGVzdCBzdHJpbmc=
echo base64_decode($res); // test string
```

in fact, decoding your string:

```
base64_decode("RVByaW50cyBhbmQg2KfZhNi52LHYqNmK2Kk=")
```

return something like this:

```
EPrints and Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ©
```

Comment: Sorry for not being more explicit, I indeed call base64_decode() and it indeed does give me `EPrints and Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ©`, but it really should give `EPrints and العربية`, so clearly there's something else missing

Comment: maybe this is a problem with page charset: try add in your page:
`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and after decode string `echo base64_decode("RVByaW50cyBhbmQg2KfZhNi52LHYqNmK2Kk=");`

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, since the text contains mixed data, I can't use `base64_decode("RVByaW50cyBhbmQg2KfZhNi52LHYqNmK2Kk=")`, but rather `base64_decode("Some Text =?utf-8?b?RVByaW50cyBhbmQg2KfZhNi52LHYqNmK2Kk=?=")`, which causes(?) the conversion to fail