# Issues reading mailbox wien Gmail and yahoo emails received - PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm reading e-mails from a mailbox on my domain. It's all ok, i'm getting overview "from" and "subject", then body content... all in UTF-8 except Gmail and yahoo mails.
I did this function:

```
function newmail($username, $password){
/* connect to server */
    $server = "mail.domain.com";
    $port = "993";
    $type = "imap";
    $secure = "ssl";
    $options = "novalidate-cert";
    $hostname = "{".$server."/".$type."/".$options."}INBOX";
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to inbox: '.$username.' on '.$server.' ' . imap_last_error());
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {
  $subjects = '';
  $senders = '';
  $bodys = '';
  $dates = '';
  /* put the newest emails on top */
  rsort($emails);
  /* for every email... */
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);
    $message = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1)));

  $senders .= iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", quoted_printable_decode($overview[0]->from))." ## ";
  $subjects .= iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", quoted_printable_decode($overview[0]->subject))." ## ";
  $bodys .= $message." ## ";
  $dates .= $overview[0]->date." ## ";
  }
}
/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
//return different parts to explode
$emails = array(
        'sender' => $senders,
        'subject' => $subjects,
        'body' => $bodys,
        'date' => $dates
    );
return $emails;
}
```

I'm doing this way cause i want to make something when read the body depending of subject etc.

The issue happen when i send an email from a gmail or yahoo account (i've not tried with outlook, only with 3/4 different domain mailing servers, gmail and yahoo).
It makes appear some glitches like:

> =?UTF-8?Q?JoÃ«l_Bo?=

i think i'm parsing well to UTF-8, otherwise it hadn't been working on other emails. The glitch i pasted...i copied it from overview ("from") part, and i have more glitch on body too.

Any idea?

- PD: i dont want to use php pear, zend or others, i want to make it with pure php. Don't mean to insert third party scripts on my one-

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to handle email parsing/decoding in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721410/best-way-to-handle-email-parsing-decoding-in-php)

Comment: not the same. cheers

Comment: Correctly parsing a MIME format email is a complex task. If you don't want to use a third party library, you will have to write hundreds of lines of PHP code to do that, which is too much for an answer on SO.